# LINQ to SQL exception: System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: linq-to-sql

Not sure why I keep getting an `OutOfMemory` exception.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC with LINQ to SQL.  Here's some of the stack trace:

> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of
>   type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.]
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IntPtr
>   method) +0
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type
>   delegateType) +7652553
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile(SqlExpression
>   expression, Type elementType) +442
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory(SqlNode
>   node, Type elemType) +100
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) +253
>   System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression) +49
>
>   System.Linq.Queryable.Single(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +301
>   WorkGrabber.Web.Models.WorkGrabberDataContext.GetJob(Int32
>   id) +233
>   WorkGrabber.Web.Controllers.BidsController.New(Int32
>   jobId) +19

Comment: It can happen without MVC. We have an application which produces the same error. We have seen it in a hosted environment. Happens really rarely, we cannot isolate it, cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your expression? The problem seems to stem from this line:

```
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType) +7652553
```

That offset seems quite strange. I can hardly believe a normal dynamic method will have a 7.5MB body.

Comment: WorkGrabber.Web.Models.WorkGrabberDataContext.GetJob(Int32 id) 

Thats just a datacontext.Jobs.Single(j=>j.JobID = id)

Could it be from the LoadOptions or something?  Where did you get the 7.5 MB body from?

Comment: From the call stack line, it shows that the error happens while at offset +7652553 from the beginning of the method call.